# Is there any way to send formdata in json field for post api?

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, multipartform-data

```
{
 name:"anc",
 logo:this must be form data,
 fimes:[{a:"ddsd","dd",},{a:'dfd'}
}
```

This JSON data should be posted to the server. logo field must be an image.  Is it possible to send the image in JSON format? In header I must send 'Accept':"application/json". If I try to post it via all the data in form data I got 422 errors.

Comment: AFAIK JSON has no data types at all. Just a syntax https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 0):

JSON has no data type that supports images per se.

If you want to pass binary data through JSON then you'll need to represent it in a format that JSON supports (e.g. a string of base64 data).

You'll need the server to be designed to recognise the encoding you use.